# No normal German keyboard layout in (K)ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, german

After the recent LTS upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, I noticed that I can no longer add the normal German keyboard layout. The only German available is German (Switzerland) with the weird default layout option EurKEY.

[image]

Is there anyway to solve or workaround that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the same on Kubuntu 16.10; it's apparently a [KDE bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176822).

The way around it is to set *Limit selection by language* to **All languages** before selecting the layout. Then you'll see multiple German options including the "normal" one.